# What is the benefit of multiple subnet (FCI/AG) in a virtualized setup?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-vm, virtualisation

In a virtualized setup, for example on-prem VMware based virtualized setup or Azure based VMs, what exactly is the benefit of placing the SQL FCI or AG nodes in separate subnet?

Answer (score 3):

In Azure the big benefit of this configuration is that you don't need an Azure Load Balancer.

"Simplify your deployment and eliminate the need for an Azure Load Balancer or distributed network name (DNN) for your Always On availability group by creating your SQL Server virtual machines (VMs) in multiple subnets within the same Azure virtual network."

[Tutorial: Configure an availability group in multiple subnets (SQL Server on Azure VMs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-manually-configure-tutorial-multi-subnet?view=azuresql)

The AG Listener has one IP in each subnet, and at most one of them is online at any time.  A DNS lookup for the AG Listener hostname returns both subnet IPs and the client simultaneously (MultiSubNetFailover=true), or after a very short delay (with TransparentNetworkIPResolution) attempts to connect to both IP addresses, and proceeds with the logon to whichever is available.

In a single subnet cluster in Azure guest VMs are not able to bring the AG listener IP online (they can bring it online in the guest but Azure networking won't recognize it).  So you need an Azure Load Balancer to host the AG Listener IP address and forward traffic to whichever node is active.

In on-prem this configuration is mostly used for geographically distributed clusters, because subnets are typically local to a single datacenter.